# How to implement signal and slots in QGraphicsRectItem? subclassed qobject and qgraphicsrectitem but getting errors

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am creating object from `QGraphicsRectItem` and adding to the `Qgraphicscene(scene)`.
I want to get every `movement(pos)` of object(`qgraphicsrectitem`) so that I subclassed `Qgraphicsrectitem`. But in this class I am getting some errors.
How can I get object position changed in scene ?

error:

> 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of '`QGraphicsRectItem`'
>        { `&QGraphicsRectItem::staticMetaObject`, `qt_meta_stringdata_ItemHandler.data`

**ItemHandler.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class ItemHandler : public QGraphicsRectItem, public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT

   public:
      ItemHandler(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0 );
     ~ItemHandler();

   protected:
      QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);

   signals:
      void objectHandlePosChanged(QPointF value);
 };
```

**ItemHandler.cpp**

```
  #include "itemhandler.h"

 ItemHandler::ItemHandler(QGraphicsItem *parent) : QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
 {
     setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
 }

 ItemHandler::~ItemHandler()
 {

 }

 QVariant ItemHandler::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, 
 const QVariant &value)
 {
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
       emit objectHandlePosChanged(newPos);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In you header file, inherit first from QObject, as follows:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class ItemHandler : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
 Q_OBJECT

   public:
      ItemHandler(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0 );
     ~ItemHandler();

   protected:
      QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);

   signals:
      void objectHandlePosChanged(QPointF value);
 };
```

And this is my test main function (sorry it's just a sandbox):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow* mywindow = new MainWindow();

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    ItemHandler *item = new ItemHandler;
    item->setRect(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0);

    scene.addItem(item);

    QApplication::connect(item, SIGNAL(objectHandlePosChanged(QPointF)), mywindow, SLOT(moved(QPointF)));

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.setFixedSize(250, 250);
    view.setWindowTitle("QGraphicsItem Test");
    item->setPos(-100, -100);
    item->setPos(-200, -200);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();

}
```

I just used an empty MainWindow that is never displayed to have a slot to connect to the signal, there's no point in having a MainWindow: it was already there and I modified it instead of creating a new class. The example works, fires the signal and displays the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..I tried this after adding to scene its not showing rectangle. By debugging get to know constructor giving qObject ptr not qgraphicsrectitem pointer

Comment: I tried it, it works and fires the objectHandlePosChanged signal. I can't help more unless you post a complete working example etc. etc.

Comment: can u post... creating instance and connect in your example...2 line code

Comment: I added a working example of how to create and connect your ItemHandler, hope it helps. Next time please put a minimal working example to reproduce the problem.